# PowerBI: Is it possible to use ALL and ALLEXCEPT together in the same CALCULATE?

Tags: powerbi

I have a model with two tables:

- Table 1 has data about emergency episodes where FichaID is the key column;
- Table 2 has data about patologies (if present in the pacientes in Table 1), where FichaID identifies each pacient. Important note: It's possible to have multiple patologies for each patient, so FichaID can be duplicated in Table 2.

I want to make a calculated measure where the dominator is a count that needs to considered as context filter the name of the institution and episode date (Both present in Table 1), but ignoring any selection of the patoligies in table 2.

I've tried multiple ways to do this but with no sucess. The measure needs to do someting like this:

```
measure1 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Table1[FichaId] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        Table1,
        Table1[institution],
        Table1[Date]
    );
    ALL ( Table2 )
)
```

What happends is that the `ALL(Table2)`  ignores all context filters considered in the `ALLEXCEPT` function. As a result the denominator is affected by patologies selection and not by institution or date.

Can any one help me solve this issue?

If necessary i can provide other information as needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please share a small reproducible example (with tables and data) with expected output?

Comment: user5226582: Sorry for not responding. I was totally focused on the problem. Just now i was able to solve the reported issue. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that Table1->Table2 connection was 1 to many, so if we want to use an all except function to handle context filters we need to use the "many" side of the connection as the reference table in the function. Take a look at the solution for the problem above:

```
measure1 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Table1[FichaId] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        Table2,
        Table1[institution],
        Table1[Date]
    )
)
```